# Hashed shard key in MongoDB on the _id so then what?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

If I do create a hashed index with `ensureIndex({ _id: "hashed"})` will Mongo know to take any queries on the `_id` field and run them against the hashed index? Or do I need to update all the queries that use _id to be the `_id_hashed`?

Comment: when you create _id:"hashed" index, it's _in addition_ to regular _id:1 index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongodb doesn't modify the `_id` field when a hashed index is created.  It will do the right thing, and query against `_id` appropriately.  The hash will only be used to query and balance the shards.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the existing "_id":1 index with "_id":"hashed" ? I have created an hashed index but the default `id` index still exists which takes up disk space and RAM.